# How to find next level of dict without knowing key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been working on a project recently and have been stumped by this problem. It goes like this:

I have a dict like so:

```
{
  '220': {
    '05': {
      'value': '23921023',
      'enable': True
    }
  },
  '250': {
    '05': {
      'value': '23921022',
      'enable': False
    }
  }
}
```

I now want to get the key, `value` but I don't consistently know what the `05` will be. How could I go about doing something like this?
`dict.get('220').get(?).get('value')`

I've tried many different things but have yet to succeed. This also assumes that there will always be only one `05` parent per key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `.values()` to get it:

```
mydict = {
  '220': {
    '05': {
      'value': '23921023',
      'enable': True
    }
  },
  '250': {
    '05': {
      'value': '23921022',
      'enable': False
    }
  }
}

print(next(iter(mydict['220'].values()))['value'])
```

Or, convert to a list:

```
print(list(mydict['220'].values())[0]['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for key in dict.get('220'):
    break
value = dict.get('220').get(key).get(value)
```

or

```
tmp = dict.get('220')
key = next(iter(tmp))
tmp.get(key).get('value')
```